# Usage of tuples as dictionary keys

Tags: python, types, dictionary, tuples, immutability

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In what case would I use a tuple as a dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938614/in-what-case-would-i-use-a-tuple-as-a-dictionary-key)

One of the advantage of tuples is that they can be used as dictionary keys in opposite to lists, as tuples are immutable and lists are mutable.

I haven't seen a useful and real example where tuples are used as dictionary keys. Could you show one or a few useful examples with smart usage of tuples as dictionary keys?

EDIT:
In many cases the resulting data structure can be implemented as a class instead of as dictionary with keys as tuples. Explain why in your example is it better to use dictionary instead of a class.

Answer (score 3):

For example, you need a dictionary for employee's,
In real world, 2 names (first and last name can be same) (i.e. 2 persons with same name) but combination of names (first and last) with phone no's can't be same.
In such a scenario, tuple as a key is required.

Answer (score 3):

You have a set of points in a 2D/3D space with properties:

```
shape = {(2,3,4) : {'visible' : False, 'color': 'red'},
         (1,0,2) : {'visible' : True, 'color': 'blue'},
         (1,2,4) : {'visible' : True, 'color': 'green'}}
```

or you have a custom dictbased relational database with e.g. a primary key
based on two rows:

```
bill_db = {('customer_a', 'date') : bill_properties,
           ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a tuple to define a cell in a chessboard:

```
cell_1 = (1, 3)
cell_2 = (2, 5)
occupied_cells = {cell_1: True, cell_2: False}

def cell_is_occupied(cell):
    return occupied_cells.get(cell, False)
```