# Efficient way to store and search coordinates in python

Tags: python, algorithm, search, coordinates

I'm writing a simple game in python(2.7) in pygame. In this game, I have to store 2D coordinates. The number of these items will start from 0 and increase by 2 in each step. They will increase up to ~6000. In each step I have to check whether 9 specific coordinates are among them, or not. I've tried to store them simply in a list as (x,y), but it is not efficient to search in such a list.

**How can I store these coordinates so it will be more efficient to search among them?**

What I was trying to do in each step:

```
# Assuming:
myList = []
co1 = (12.3,20.2) # and so on..
valuesToCheck = [co1,co2,co3,co4,co5,co6,co7,co8,co9]

# In each step:
# Adding 2 coordinates
myList.append((x1,y1))
myList.append((x2,y2))
# Searching 9 specific coordinates among all
for coordinate in valuesToCheck:
    if coordinate in myList:
        print "Hit!"
        break
# Note that the valuesToCheck will change in each step.
del valuesToCheck[0]
valuesToCheck.append(co10)
```

Coordinates are floating point numbers, and their highest values are limited. They start from (0.0,0.0) to (1200.0,700.0).

I've searched about this but stored values were either string or constant numbers.

Comment: Is the only search you need to do on the coordinate set is whether the 9 special coordinates are in there?  Do these 9 special coords change (if not, why not throw out the 2D points that do not match)?  Any other searches you need to do on your points?

Comment: As I added in the code part, these 9 special coordinates change in each step too.
There are no other searches to do on points though.

Comment: In this case with this number of items I would keep it simple and use a dict. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938614/in-what-case-would-i-use-a-tuple-as-a-dictionary-key

Comment: Tuples are hashable and immutable, so putting them into a set to check for existence would work. Alternatively, if you need to associate a value, a dictionary would work.

Comment: Are the coordinates always integers? And, are they always constrained by maximum/minimum values? (ex. they will never be smaller than (0,0) or larger than (500,500))

Comment: Coordinates are floating point numbers, and yes, they are limited. 
They start from (0.0,0.0) to (1200.0,700.0)

Comment: Ah, if they were integers, I was going to suggest storing the coordinates in a 1200-by-700 2d list. But you can't do that with floats. Just as well, it would have taken up a lot of memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maintain a [set](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) alongside your list, or replacing the list entirely if you have no other use for it. Membership checking and adding are [O(1) on average](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for sets, so your overall algorithm will be O(N) compared to the O(N^2) of just using a list.

```
myList = []
mySet = set()
co1 = (12,20) # and so on..
valuesToCheck = [co1,co2,co3,co4,co5,co6,co7,co8,co9]

# In each step:
# Adding 2 coordinates
myList.append((x1,y1))
myList.append((x2,y2))
mySet.add((x1, y1))
mySet.add((x2, y2))
# Searching 9 specific coordinates among all
for coordinate in valuesToCheck:
    if coordinate in mySet:
        print "Hit!"
        break
# Note that the valuesToCheck will change in each step.

del valuesToCheck[0]
valuesToCheck.append(co10)
```

Comment: Will using a set be more efficient than using a dict.?
And is there any more sophisticated but efficient ways?
(I'm looking for the [**K-d tree**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)   @angelatlarge suggested)

Comment: As I understand it, sets are implemented as dicts by the back end, so the efficiency will be the same. I am not aware of more efficient ways, although I can't discount their existence.

Comment: Why would it be `O(N^2)` ? Wouldn't it just be O(1) for the list append and O(n) for the list lookup?

Comment: @Davos, I think I misread the problem the first time around - I thought that `valuesToCheck` grew in size proportionally with `myList`. So doing list lookup inside a `for coordinate in valuesToCheck:` loop would have been O(N^2).  But on second look I expect `valuesToCheck` never gets bigger than nine elements, so the OP's original code would be O(N). I still recommend the set approach, which, given a constant-sized valuesToCheck, becomes O(1) total.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me, I assumed you were right and were going to point out what I'd missed. Yes of course, my comment is completely orthogonal to the Q&A. In my case I am going with a dict that uses tuples as keys because I want to store data with coordinates, thanks for your additional link to complexity and also the info about sets being implemented as dicts. That link backs up that claim exactly under `Sets` : "See dict -- the implementation is intentionally very similar"

Comment: @SweeneyTodd You can't use a dictionary for coordinates because a dictionary can only have one Y value for an X value. So coordinates with the same X value will overwrite each other.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, you're adding elements to `myList`, but never removing them. You're then testing every element of `valuesToCheck` for memebership in `myList`.

If that's the case, you could boost performance by converting myList to a set instead of a list. Testing for membership in a list is O(n), while testing for membership in a set is typically O(1).

Your syntax will remain mostly unchanged:

```
mySet = set()

# your code

# Adding 2 coordinates
mySet.add((x1,y1))
mySet.add((x2,y2))
# Searching 9 specific coordinates among all
for coordinate in valuesToCheck:
    if coordinate in mySet:
        print "Hit!"
        break
# Note that the valuesToCheck will change in each step.
del valuesToCheck[0]
valuesToCheck.append(co10)
```

Comment: Will using a set be more efficient than using a dict.?
And is there any more sophisticated but efficient ways?
(I'm looking for the [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)  **K-d tree**.  @angelatlarge suggested)

Comment: @SweeneyTodd- If all you're doing is checking for membership, a `dict` and `set` will perform essentially the same operation. Regarding more sophisticated methods: I would first consider developing some metrics for how fast this section of code needs to be before it's "good enough". Premature optimization is the root of all evil and all that :)