# How to check if dictionary has certain key (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I'm having a defaultdict dictionary that has keys like this:

```
RJECNIK['*','A']['<A>']
```

now i don't know how to check if there is a key, for example:

```
a=list(RJECNIK.keys())
```

gives me the list of only first keys (['*','A']).
In my code I need an if statement

if key in RJECNIK:
    ...

But it doesn't work since I don't know how to check for a PAIR of keys in defaultdict with 2 keys.

Comment: You are confusing a multidimensional dictionary (which Python does not have) with a dictionary of dictionaries (which is what `RJECNIK` is).

Comment: I don't understand your question and I don't understand that `RJECNIK['*','A']['<A>']` notation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to check for both keys in both dictionaries:

```
key = ('*', '<A>')
if key[0] in RJECNIK and key[1] in RJECNIK[key[0]]:
    pass
```

Comment: Seems like it could be generalised with `reduce` if the nesting is arbitrarily deep.

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked! I may have confused you all, I should have made it more simple, but you got the point.

Answer (score 2):

From here: ['has_key()' or 'in'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323410/has-key-or-in)

```
if ("*","A") in RJECNIK:
    print "key is in dictionary"
```

According to this [In what case would I use a tuple as a dictionary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938614/in-what-case-would-i-use-a-tuple-as-a-dictionary-key) you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You are using tuples as dictionary keys; `'*', 'A'` is just another way to spell the tuple `('*', 'A')`. So

```
if ('*', 'A') in RJECNIK:
```

should be True.