# Find the closest color to a color, from given list of colors

Tags: python, rgb

I have a list of 20 colors, each is like this (0,0,0)(rgb) but with different values, and i need to find the closest to the color i am giving, for example (200, 191, 231). problem is i am not sure how i should check what color is the closes, and how am i suppose to set all these color values, in a list? in an array?

I've been thinking maybe add all the color for exmaple (1,2,3) = 4 an then find the closest but i am not sure if its a good idea..

Here's a list of the colors:

```
#(0, 0, 0) - Black
#(127, 127, 127) - Gray
#(136, 0, 21) - Bordeaux
#(237, 28, 36) - red
#(255, 127, 39) - orange
#(255, 242, 0) - yellow
#(34, 177, 76) - green
#(203, 228, 253) - blue
#(0, 162, 232) - dark blue
#(63, 72, 204) - purple
#(255, 255, 255) - white
#(195, 195, 195) - light gray
#(185, 122, 87) - light brown
#(255, 174, 201) - light pink
#(255, 201, 14) - dark yellow
#(239, 228, 176) - light yellow
#(181, 230, 29) - light green
#(153, 217, 234) - light blue
#(112, 146, 190) - dark blue
#(200, 191, 231) - light purple
```

And here is the function:

```
def paint(pixel):
  r,g,b,a = pix[x,y]
  print(str(r) + ' '+  str(g) + ' ' + str(b))
  sleep(0.20)
```

If you come up with a good solution or have any question please replay thank you for your help!

Comment: I think probably finding the euclidean distance between the colour vectors would be a sensible option `sqrt(sum of squared distances of individual components)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python PIL - Finding Nearest Color (Rounding Colors)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34366981/python-pil-finding-nearest-color-rounding-colors)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to find the sum of the absolute difference between the red, green and blue numbers and choose the smallest one.

```
from math import sqrt

COLORS = (
    (181, 230, 99),
    (23, 186, 241),
    (99, 23, 153),
    (231, 99, 29),
)

def closest_color(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb
    color_diffs = []
    for color in COLORS:
        cr, cg, cb = color
        color_diff = sqrt((r - cr)**2 + (g - cg)**2 + (b - cb)**2)
        color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
    return min(color_diffs)[1]

closest_color((12, 34, 156))
# => (99, 23, 153)

closest_color((23, 145, 234))
# => (23, 186, 241)
```

EDIT: Improved code and used Euclidian distance calculation Sven mentioned above instead of basic diff sum.

Comment: Your solution doesnt consider more colors with same distance. It is wrong solution

Comment: Good, but not very fast though...

Answer (score 23):

**Fast, efficient and clean solution**

*Lets say we have:*

```
list_of_colors = [[255,0,0],[150,33,77],[75,99,23],[45,88,250],[250,0,255]]
```

For fast processing use numpy and transform into numpy array

```
import numpy as np
```

desired color

```
color = [155,155,155]
```

**Complete code**

```
import numpy as np

list_of_colors = [[255,0,0],[150,33,77],[75,99,23],[45,88,250],[250,0,255]]
color = [155,155,155]

def closest(colors,color):
    colors = np.array(colors)
    color = np.array(color)
    distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors-color)**2,axis=1))
    index_of_smallest = np.where(distances==np.amin(distances))
    smallest_distance = colors[index_of_smallest]
    return smallest_distance 

closest_color = closest(list_of_colors,color)
print(closest_color )
```

**This algorithm is without loops and is super fast as it uses numpy**

Comment: thank you for your solution. since we traverse each pixel it still takes too much time. can you think of another solution where we don't traverse the image with 2 for-loops? it seems like vectorize is the same as a loop, and apply methods don't work with this function where the color variable is a list with 3 elements.

Comment: @stackmodern this is the solution where you dont traverse with loops. You can apply it on images too, but you have to play around axis value

Comment: yes, i know this solution does not traverse with loops. i am asking an additional question. i guess there is no solution to traverse an image with this function without 2 loops.

Comment: @stackmodern Can you describe your problem in more detail? You want to to pass whole image?

Comment: i want to perform closest_color function for the whole image, pixel by pixel. it takes about 20 seconds per image since i use two for loops (100.000 image dataset is impossible with this speed). my additional question is this, can you perform this function in a whole image, without using nested two loops (is there a more numpy-style solution)? your finding-closest-color algorithm is perfect in terms of speed, but how can i efficiently perform this function to a whole image?

Comment: @stackmodern You should check numpy api. This pretty much works on images too. a) you need to pass list_of_colors as numpy array with this shape (x,y,3) [that is standard image shape in numpy form] and in the function change axis=2. Try it yourself. list_of_colors = np.ones(shape=[100,100,3]) where 3 is rgb channel. axis=2 means you make operations on 3rd dimension, which is rgb channel. If you have grayscaled image, just dont use 3 as rgb channel, but 1, so for example (100,100,1). If you use (100,100) you need to change again axis=...

Comment: i cant understand it. so list_of_colors is what we return at the end of function? from your closest function, we input the whole image instead of a pixel, then we change axis 1 to 2? Sorry to bother, but if it cannot be summed up in one comment, i would like to ask a new question and link it here

Comment: closest function accepts list or numpy array of this dimension: (n,3) where n(0. index) is number of items in list/array and  3 (1.index) is color channel. Therefore axis=1 (1.index), because it calculates stuff over rgb channel. If you want to calculate this for image (n,m,3) where 3(2.index) is rgb chanell, you need to change this line `distances = np.sqrt(np.sum((colors-color)**2,axis=1))` to acces rgb channel, that is 2. index of array, so axis=2. And thats it

Comment: in my case i have 77 rgb colors to pick from so colors shape is (77,3). But I have an image with 3 dimensions. It always end up in a broadcast errors

Comment: @stackmodern either you understand how numpy works (which is about what i wrote minute ago with dimension) or you take your image as numpy array and use this command: image.reshape(-1,3) and you will be fine without chaning anything. If you still dont understand, you need to learn how numpy works. I suggest you learn numpy, then you will very easily modify this function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241315/discussion-between-stackmodern-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

You can place the colors into an octree, then walk down it until you either find the exact color, or reach the end and take the color of the node with the smallest Euclidean distance. This way, you only have to calculate Euclidean distance a max of 8 times (0 if you hit the exact color before that).

Here's how, in C# at least: https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1046574/octtree-based-nearest-color-search