# How to make this loop faster?

Tags: python, performance, loops, optimization

I want my image to have only 10 specific colors, specified in color_list.
So I loop through every pixel and if the color of that pixel is not included in the color list, I assign the color of the neighboring region. But since the images are 2k by 2k pixels. This loop takes 3minutes or so.
I'm sure my way of doing this is not optimal. How can I optimize my way of doing this?

```
atlas_img_marked, atlas_img_cleaned = clean_img_pixels(atlas_img, color_list)

def clean_img_pixels(atlas_img, color_list):
    dd = 3
    for ii in range(atlas_img.shape[0]-1):
        for jj in range(atlas_img.shape[1]-1):
            pixelcolor = (atlas_img[ii,jj,0],atlas_img[ii,jj,1],atlas_img[ii,jj,2])
            if pixelcolor not in color_list:
                pixel2color = (atlas_img[ii-dd,jj,0],atlas_img[ii-dd,jj,1],atlas_img[ii-dd,jj,2])
                if (pixel2color == (0,0,0)) | (pixel2color not in color_list):
                    pixel2color = (atlas_img[ii+dd,jj,0],atlas_img[ii+dd,jj,1],atlas_img[ii+dd,jj,2])
                    if (pixel2color == (0,0,0)) | (pixel2color not in color_list):
                        pixel2color = (atlas_img[ii+5,jj,0],atlas_img[ii+5,jj,1],atlas_img[ii+5,jj,2])
                atlas_img_cleaned[ii,jj] = pixel2color
    return atlas_img_cleaned
```

To be more precise, here is the part which takes the longest:

```
out_colors = []
for ii in range(atlas_img.shape[0]-1):
    for jj in range(atlas_img.shape[1]-1):
        pixelcolor = (atlas_img[ii,jj,0],atlas_img[ii,jj,1],atlas_img[ii,jj,2])
        if pixelcolor not in color_list:
            out_colors.append((ii,jj))
```

takes 177 seconds

Tried it in this way:

```
out_colors = [(ii,jj) for (ii,jj) in itertools.product(range(atlas_img.shape[0]), range(atlas_img.shape[1])) if (atlas_img[ii,jj,0],atlas_img[ii,jj,1],atlas_img[ii,jj,2]) not in color_list]
```

But doesn't make much of a difference. takes 173 seconds

This is the color list:

```
color_list = [(52, 26, 75), (9, 165, 216), (245, 34, 208), (146, 185, 85), (251, 6, 217), (223, 144, 239), (190, 224, 121), (252, 26, 157), (150, 130, 142), (51, 129, 172), (97, 85, 204), (1, 108, 233), (138, 201, 180), (210, 63, 175), (26, 138, 43), (216, 141, 61), (38, 89, 118), (0, 0, 0)]
```

Here is an example image
[image]

Comment: Making `color_list` a `set` might get you some improvement.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure if that's what's making it slow

Comment: Use a profiler and see where it spends most of the time. Some easy things to try could be: swapping your for loops and reduce the amount of if statements. The list vs. set should also give you some tangible amount of runtime.

Comment: if you have it as numpy array then you should use numpy functions instead of `for`-loops. `For`-loops slow down numpy code a lot.

Comment: Can you share more code and an example image maybe? I also guess it's RGB pillow and numpy, but I'm also having a difficult time to actually run this myself, there are several out of bounds conditions in there (ii+dd, ii+5) which just blow up with a random image.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I now added the example image and color_list

Comment: @furas yes image is a numpy . Would you give me an example of how to use numpy functions instead of for loops?

Comment: The algorithm does not ensure all pixel colors are in the color set.

Comment: @JeremyWhitcher the goal is not to ensure all are in the color_list. The goal is to find the ones that aren't, and change their color

Comment: @snakecharmerb So using sets instead of list did make a difference. Thanks. 
using PIL, reduced runtime from 177s to 4s. And using sets, further reduced it to 3sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ditch `numpy` altogether and directly operate with Pillow arrays and use the tuple set instead of a list, it's much faster (for me this executes in 5s on your example picture):

```
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime

im = Image.open('7y1JG.png')
im = im.convert('RGB')

color_list = {(52, 26, 75), (9, 165, 216), (245, 34, 208), (146, 185, 85), (251, 6, 217), (223, 144, 239),
              (190, 224, 121), (252, 26, 157), (150, 130, 142), (51, 129, 172), (97, 85, 204), (1, 108, 233),
              (138, 201, 180), (210, 63, 175), (26, 138, 43), (216, 141, 61), (38, 89, 118), (0, 0, 0)}


def clean_img_pixels(atlas_img, color_list):
    atlas_img_cleaned = atlas_img.copy().load()
    dd = 3
    for ii in range(atlas_img.size[0] - 1):
        for jj in range(atlas_img.size[1] - 1):
            if atlas_img.getpixel((ii, jj)) not in color_list:
                pixel2_color = atlas_img.getpixel((ii - dd, jj))
                if (pixel2_color == (0, 0, 0)) | (pixel2_color not in color_list):
                    pixel2_color = atlas_img.getpixel((ii + dd, jj))
                    if (pixel2_color == (0, 0, 0)) | (pixel2_color not in color_list):
                        pixel2_color = atlas_img.getpixel((ii + 5, jj))
                atlas_img_cleaned[ii, jj] = pixel2_color
    return atlas_img_cleaned


start_time = datetime.now()

out_image = clean_img_pixels(im, color_list)
time_elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time
print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(time_elapsed))
```

I'd still advise you to do some additional boundary checking, it just so happens to run because of the way your image is laid out.

Comment: Amazing! thanks Thomas. It's unbelievable how the run time was reduced from 177s to 4s!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with based on the problem statement, Thomas Jungblut's answer and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242194/python-find-the-closest-color-to-a-color-from-giving-list-of-colors).

The algorithm performs a single pixel lookup and results in an image limited to colors in COLOR_LIST.

```
from PIL import Image
from datetime import datetime
from math import sqrt

COLOR_LIST = {(52, 26, 75), (9, 165, 216), (245, 34, 208), (146, 185, 85), (251, 6, 217), (223, 144, 239),
              (190, 224, 121), (252, 26, 157), (150, 130, 142), (51, 129, 172), (97, 85, 204), (1, 108, 233),
              (138, 201, 180), (210, 63, 175), (26, 138, 43), (216, 141, 61), (38, 89, 118), (0, 0, 0)}
COLOR_CACHE = {}

def closest_color(rgb, color_list):
    if rgb not in COLOR_CACHE:
        r, g, b = rgb
        color_diffs = []
        for color in color_list:
            cr, cg, cb = color
            color_diff = sqrt(abs(r - cr)**2 + abs(g - cg)**2 + abs(b - cb)**2)
            color_diffs.append((color_diff, color))
        COLOR_CACHE[rgb] = min(color_diffs)[1]
    return COLOR_CACHE[rgb]

def clean_img_pixels(atlas_img, color_list):
    atlas_img_cleaned = atlas_img.copy()
    pixels = atlas_img_cleaned.load()
    for ii in range(atlas_img.size[0] - 1):
        for jj in range(atlas_img.size[1] - 1):
            pixel = atlas_img.getpixel((ii, jj))
            if pixel not in color_list:
                pixels[ii, jj] = closest_color(pixel, color_list)
    return atlas_img_cleaned

im = Image.open('7y1JG.png')
im = im.convert('RGB')
start_time = datetime.now()
om = clean_img_pixels(im, COLOR_LIST)
print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(datetime.now() - start_time))
om.save('7y1JG-clean.png', "PNG")

# Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) 0:00:02.932316
```

Comment: thanks Jeremy. But in my case, the pixels surrounding a region might not necessarily have the closest color to that region. So this might cause lot of pixel colors in unwanted places.
So in my code I tried to find the adjacent regions, and replace the pixel color by those. It was just slow. Which is now fixed by using only PIL