# Distinguish similar RGB pixels from noisey background?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Context: I am trying to find the directional heading from a small image of a compass. Directional heading meaning if the red (north) point is 90 degrees counter-clockwise from the top, the viewer is facing East, 180 degrees is south, 270 is west, 0 is north. etc. I understand there are limitations with such a small blurry image but I'd like to be as accurate as possible. The compass is overlaid on street view imagery meaning the background is noisy and unpredictable.

[image]

The first strategy I thought of was to find the red pixel that is furthest away from the center and calculate the directional heading from that. The math is simple enough.

The tough part for me is differentiating the red pixels from everything else. Especially because almost any color could be in the background.

My first thought was to black out the completely transparent parts to eliminate the everything but the white transparent ring and the tips of the compass.

[image]
[image]
[image]
`True Compass Values: 35.9901, 84.8366, 104.4101`

[image]
[image]
[image]
`These values are taken from the source code.`

I then used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54242348/12759363) to find the closest RGB value to a user given list of colors. After calibrating the list of colors I was able to create a list that found some of the compass's inner most pixels. This yielded the correct result within +/- 3 degrees. However, when I tried altering the list to include every pixel of the red compass tip, there would be background pixels that would be registered as "red" and therefore mess up the calculation.

I have manually found the end of the tip using [this tool](https://yangcha.github.io/iview/iview.html) and the result always ends up within +/- 1 degree ( .5 in most cases ) so I hope this should be possible

The original RGB value of the red in the compass is (184, 42, 42) and (204, 47, 48) but the images are from screenshots of a video which results in the tip/edge pixels being blurred and blackish/greyish.

[image]

Is there a better way of going about this than the closest_color() method? If so, what, if not, how can I calibrate a list of colors that will work?

Comment: Is the compass always the same size in the image... I mean is it always 1/16 of the total image width or somesuch?

Comment: Interesting. Could you provide un-blacked-out versions of those three images, for testing purposes? Also, unless I'm missing something, your text describes the angle as increasing clockwise from north, but your labeled examples go counterclockwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have hard time constraints (e.g. live detection from video), and willing to switch to NumPy, OpenCV, and scikit-image, you might use [template matching](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html). You can derive quite a good template (and mask) from the image of the needle you provided. In some loop, you'll iterate angles from 0° to 360° with a desired resolution – the finer the longer takes the whole procedure – and perform the template matching. For each angle, you save the value of the best match, and finally search for the best score over all angles.

That'd be my code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.transform import rotate

# Set up template (and mask) for template matching
templ = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('templ_compass.png')[2:-2, :], (23, 69))
templ = cv2.cvtColor(templ, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)
templ[..., 3] = cv2.cvtColor(
    cv2.addWeighted(templ[..., :3], 0.5,
                    cv2.flip(templ[..., :3], 0), 0.5, 0), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
templ[..., 3] = cv2.threshold(templ[..., 3], 254, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]

# Collect image file names
images = ['compass_36.png', 'compass_85.png', 'compass_104.png']

# Initialize angles and minimum values
angles = np.arange(0, 360, 1)
min_vals = np.zeros_like(angles)

# Iterate image file names
for image in images:

    # Read image
    img = cv2.imread(image).astype(np.float32) / 255

    # Iterate angles
    for i_a, angle in enumerate(angles):

        # Rotate template and mask
        templ_rot = rotate(templ.copy(), angle, resize=True).astype(np.float32)

        # Actual template matching
        result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, templ_rot[..., :3], cv2.TM_SQDIFF,
                                   mask=templ_rot[..., 3])

        # Save minimum value
        min_vals[i_a] = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)[0]

    # Find best match angle
    best_match_idx = np.argmin(min_vals)
    print('{}: {}'.format(image, angles[best_match_idx]))
```

And, these are the results:

```
compass_36.png: 37
compass_85.png: 85
compass_104.png: 104
```

If you switch the angle resolution to `angles = np.arange(0, 360, 0.5)`, you get:

```
compass_36.png: 36.5
compass_85.png: 85.0
compass_104.png: 104.5
```

Setting up the template involved some manual work, e.g. properly cropping the needle, getting an appropriate size, and deriving a good mask.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.3
OpenCV:        4.5.2
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Nice work - if @Wellwoah is feeling keen, it could probably be parallelised across multiple processes quite well to - either sending successive images to different processes or doing say 90 degrees per process across 4 processes.

Comment: I wonder if it might be faster to use both approaches. Depending on how long things take, it could make sense to use the asker's original approach, then apply this process to each angle within +/- a few degrees of the result in order to get better accuracy.